# remix return redirect from action function called by browser fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, remix.run

Is it possible to redirect from an action function when you posted to it using `fetch` instead of `Form` or `useSubmit`?

example: (this doesn't work...)

```typescript
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const data = await request.json();
  return redirect(`${data.redirectTo}`);
};

const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(async () => {
      const data = { redirectTo: "/home" };
      await fetch("test", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
    }, 2500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

I **can** see in the network tab the new GET `/home` but there is no actual `redirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a redirect `Response` from an `action` you won't be redirected from the `action` itself, but rather from the component or hook that made the request (the same applies for `loader`).

In your case you could simply use a fetcher:

```
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const data = await request.formData();
  return redirect(data.get("redirectTo") as string);
};

const Component = () => {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(async () => {
      const data = { redirectTo: "/home" };
      fetcher.submit(data, { method: "post" });
    }, 2500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

> I can see in the network tab the new `GET` /home but there is no actual redirect

Sure there is, this is how the redirect response works!

Try to `console.log` the `status` from the response:

```
const response = await fetch("test", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
});

console.log(response.status); // 200, not 302
```

When `fetch` gets a redirect response, automatically forge a new request to the redirection url, this is why you see a `get` to `/home`.

But once that `fetch` get the response from `/home` what will happen?

Nothing, `fetch` has no clue on how to treat this response.

This is why you aren't redirected to `/home` with `fetch`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I ended up doing
It does say in the docs to use `fetcher` if you dont want a submit redirect